# IOS and Android simulator cannot load expo project or Metro bundler in browser

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am new to React development and I have been trying to run my application locally. Any advice for the following problems is greatly appreciated! I have been trying to fix this for weeks with no success.

Version context:
[Versions of node, yarn, npm, and expo that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9GCL.png)

- When I run yarn IOS or expo start IOS/android, Metro Bundler does not open in browser. While there are critical dependency issues with expo-cli, the simulators themselves open correctly.

[Metro bundler starts and does not open in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89MkJ.png)

- Opening the web simulation works perfectly fine; however, the IOS and Android simulators do not open. Here are the following errors.

[justifyContent error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbIXg.png)

[Main not registered error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRE1m.png)

Answer (score 0):

All was resolved. I was unable to find justifyContent error in the past but I used VS Code to find it in one of my src files.